# Can I play DVDs from a DVD player on an Apple Cinema Display 23-Inch (Aluminum)?

Tags: video, display, dvd, cinema-display, blu-ray

I've seen a good price on a refurbished Apple Cinema Display, the 23-inch Aluminium version that was sold between 2004 and 2008. [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/monitors/apple/studio_cinema/specs/apple_cinema_display_23.html) says this display has a DVI port.

Will I be able to connect the HDMI output from a standard DVD or Blu-ray player to this display, via a suitable cable or adapter, and watch DVDs on it, or is there something I've missed that would prevent this working?

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks but I don't think your understanding of video is correct - as Matthieu's answer says, it's not that the DVD player can't 'drive' a monitor, it's that this monitor lacks some copy-protection technology that more modern displays have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK these display are not HDCP compliant therefore you'll have some troubles watching movies that have these protections.

Comment: Thanks, now I know what acronym to search for I've done some more research and it seems this is correct. Apparently most displays made from around 2009 onwards, which should include any with an HDMI port, are HDCP compliant but this Cinema Display is too old.